# VB.NET - Automatically initialize extended property of type Object

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I am building a code behind page that has a public property (MyDTOItem) which is essentially a DTO object (dtDTOItem) Note: In my code the Get and Set are actually real code (I stripped it for the example).

The problem I am having is in the Page_Load event.  When I set the .Member1 property of the DTO object the Get code runs and not the Set and therefore the DTO ibject property .Member1 never gets assigned.

I figured out that if I add code (MyDTOItem = New dtDTOItem) to the Page_Load event then it will set the value correctly.  What I am trying to figure out is how to initialize the property object without having to do it explicitly.  It has to be an extended property because I have custom Get and Set code.

Thank you in advance.

```
Public Property MyDTOItem As dtDTOItem
    Get

    End Get
    Set(value As dtDTOItem)

    End Set
 End Property


<DataContract(), Serializable()> _
Public Class dtDTOItem

  <DataMember()> _
  Property Member1 As String = ""

  <DataMember()> _
  Property Member2 As String = ""

  <DataMember()> _
  Property Member3 As String = ""

End Class


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MyDTOItem.Member1 = "temp string"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate the field that backs your MyDTOItem property before attempting to set property values on it.  You don't get to cheat and not instatiate an object before you start messing with its members.

Example:

Private oBackingField As SomeObject = New SomeObject

Public Property VisibleProperty As SomeObject
Get

End Get
.... etc.

No events involved.  Well.. it probably works out to the Init or PreInit event.. but you dont have to worry your pretty little head about that.

EDIT 2

Prior to .NET 4 you had to craft all your properties with backing fields, and even still to this day if you provide property accessors you must provide your own backing field... it looked like this:

```
Private backingField As DataType = New DataType  ' Create backing field and initialize it

Public Property forwardFacingProperty As DataType
Get
  Return backingField
End Get
Set (byval tValue as DataType)
  backingField = tValue
End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Which event do you recommend that I do that in?

Comment: The funny thing is that if I use automatic properties then I can create my instance:

Comment: Public Property MyDTOItem As dtDTOItem = New dtDTOItem works, but as soon as I extend the property I don't "get to cheat" and have to create the object somewhere.

Comment: How does VisibleProperty map to oBackingField.  I don't see the relationship.

Comment: I am finding that even with a Private property defined unless I construct the public property then the system return and object not defined error. So I have to explicitly define forwardFacingProperty = New DataType

Comment: not if you instantiate/initialize the backing field when you declare it:  `Private backingField As DataType = New DataType`

Comment: a property is just a convenient way of grouping 2 functions.. in fact they are implemented as functions behind-the-scenes.  So the get accessor would look like `Function GetProperty() As DataType`, and the set accessor would look like `Sub SetProperty(ByVal value As DataType)`.  NETfx 4 helps to hide this implementation detail from you by giving you syntax like `Public Property aProp As DataType [= New DataType]`.. but this is accomplished by auto-generating a backing field for you.  Your property value must be stored *somewhere*

Comment: I guess ultimately it has to be created somewhere.  In my real life example the private property was actually a session variable and the work around was to check the session variable, if nothing existed create new object and assign to session, then return the session variable.  I suppose it's the same thing, but the main thing is that the property must be created somewhere

Comment: If you have a decent default value you can always assign it in the get accessor if the backing field (session var) is null.

Comment: That is actually what I ended up doing.  Good estimated guess. :)